# Builds from Android Studio Windows start slower on device than builds from Android Studio Mac OS

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android project and up until a few weeks ago I worked on a macbook on it. The builds were starting instantly after Android Studio installed them on the device.

After I've moved to a new windows laptop running the same version of Android Studio and JDK 8 I've noticed the builds start a lot slower. By that I mean that after AS has installed and ran the app, the app stays in a white screen for about 4-5 seconds on average (up to 15-20seconds) after the first activity runs.

Videos:

Building on Mac OS: https://youtu.be/H55mfxOoBbM

Building on Windows: https://youtu.be/-7FphwiMvs8

It feels like when you're running in debug mode and it's waiting for the debug process to attach. I don't remember if I changed the settings in my Android Studio on mac because I've been migrating the configs for over 3 years.

What do I have to do to fix this?

EDIT: My guess would be that the windows bulid triggers the jit compiler.

Android Studio 2.1.2

Java 1.8 u91

Project gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build gradle file:

```
 /*
 * Gets the version name from the latest Git tag
 */

def getVersionName = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def command = 'git'

    if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
        command = 'C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe'
    }

    exec {
        commandLine command, 'describe', '--tags'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}

project.ext.versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

def getBuildNumber() {
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(project.versionPropsFile))
    def buildNumber = versionProps['artifactBuildNumber'].toInteger() + 1
    versionProps['artifactBuildNumber'] = buildNumber.toString()
    versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
    return buildNumber
}

def getReleaseVersionCode() {
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(project.versionPropsFile))
    def code = versionProps['artifactReleaseVersionCode'].toInteger()
    return code
}

def getDevVersionCode() {
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(project.versionPropsFile))
    def code = versionProps['artifactDebugVersionCode'].toInteger()
    return code
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.senic.nuimoapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionName getVersionName()
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-" + getBuildNumber() + "-DEBUG"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            versionCode getDevVersionCode()
        }
        prod {
            versionCode getReleaseVersionCode()
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/beans.xml'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.0'
    // View binder
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    // DB and ORM
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    // Json parser
    compile 'org.immutables:gson:2.1.14'
    // Nuimo sdk
    compile 'com.senic:nuimo-android:0.5.1'
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.0'
//    compile project(':..:nuimo-android:nuimo')
    // Bug tracker
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // LIFX Lan SDK
    compile 'com.github.getsenic:lifx-sdk-android:0.5.11@aar'
    // Philips Hue SDK
    compile files('libs/huelocalsdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/huesdkresources.jar')
    // OTA firmware update library
    compile 'no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:0.6.3'
    // Rest helper library
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    // Upnp Library for Sonos or Raumfeld
    compile files('libs/cling-core-2.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/cling-support-2.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/seamless-http-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/seamless-util-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/seamless-xml-1.1.1.jar')
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.19.v20160209'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.19.v20160209'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.19.v20160209'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.20'
    // Custom color picker (for Lifx and Philips Hue)
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
}
```

Comment: You are running a different platform on different hardware. There are millions of potential reasons, why a certain complex operation has different runtime characteristics.

Comment: Debug builds should depend on the settings in build.gradle and the compiler. Something that impacts builds so much should be easy to determine. EDIT: by debug builds I mean non production builds, not debug with breakpoints.

Comment: You are running on completely different hardware. Why do you insist, that the hardware should not have any effect?

Comment: Please read again. I'm not saying the build time is slow. It's that the start up time for the apk is much slower for the one built on Windows.

Comment: I didn't suggest that the build times were slower or faster. I said that you are comparing apples to oranges, and then you are surprised, when someone points out, that comparing apples to oranges isn't going to be very meaningful.

Comment: I understand but you didn't specify why they could be so different so your answer wasn't helpful at all. Answering that it's because Windows on i7 vs Mac OS on i5 is not an answer.

Comment: A comment is not an answer. Not sure, why you'd think otherwise. Since you haven't done so, taking the [tour] is highly recommended. Back to the topic: Different hardware platforms have different virtualization features, and different operating systems have different (default) configurations for those features. Since you never even provided the information, what hardware you are using (*"new laptop"* isn't very helpful), or what operating systems you are running, nor the virtualization configurations, you cannot hope to get a good answer.

Comment: Tested on an Razer Blade 2016 i7 6700q, 16gb ddr4, windows 10 x64 and on an Asus ROG G20 desktop i5 4460k, 16gb ddr3 and windows 10 x64. Both with fresh installs of Android Studio 2.1.2, gradle 2.1.2,, and JDK 1.8 u91. And they both build slow starting apks. I doubt that java on i5, i7, different ram would produce different bytecode. The same version of java on every os will produce the same bytecode. Most likely it's different default configurations for Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the 1st answer in this thread: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215000#c1

The culprit was... **instant run**. Disabled it and it's just as fast as before.